# FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. M

Tags: hive

I am new to Hive. I have set up hive and I am using mysql to store the metadata for hive tables. I am able to launch hive. However when I try to create a simple table.

I get this error:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Exception thrown when executing query : SELECT DISTINCT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTable' AS `NUCLEUS_TYPE`,

Here is what I tried,
hive> create external table employee (FirstName string,LastName string, EmployeeId string)

> row format delimited
>   fields terminated by ',';

I have been doing some research but no luck..What could I be doing wrong?